# efcore change modified state to update entity is not working with sub data objects

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I set up a Generic repository using this code for update

```
private void AttachIfNot(TEntity entityToActive)
{
    if (_dbContext.Entry(entityToActive).State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(entityToActive);
    }
}

private void UpdateEntity(TEntity entityToUpdate)
{
    AttachIfNot(entityToUpdate);
    _dbContext.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

It just attach the entity and set the modified state to save.

But when I use efocre ownsone to map a value object,the update entity function is not working.

I found out that it only works when I set Valueobject to modified too.

```
_dbContext.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified; 
_dbContext.Entry(entityToUpdate.Valueobject).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

But It is hard for me to specify all the value objects in a Generic Repository.

This is code also has problems with one to many or other relations.
The working way is like this:

```
Classroom classroom = new Classroom
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "b",
    Students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student()
        {
            Name = "aa",
            Id = 2
         }
    }
};

if (_defaultDbContext.Entry(classroom).State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    _defaultDbContext.Classrooms.Attach(classroom);
    foreach(var stu in classroom.Students)
    {
        _defaultDbContext.Students.Attach(stu);
    }
}

_defaultDbContext.Entry(classroom).State = EntityState.Modified;
foreach (var stu in classroom.Students)
{
    _defaultDbContext.Entry(stu).State  = EntityState.Modified;
}

_defaultDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I found out one way is get the entity form repo then update it using automapper:

```
targetEntity = repo.GetById(entityId);
automapper.map(souceEntity,targetEntity);
//or
automapper.map(souceDto,targetEntity);
_dbContext.Save();
```

The entity comes by query, so the change will be tracked.

But I  have to configure the automapper with this entity map when I want to change entity

```
CreateMap<EntityType, EntityType>();
```

I think it's not the best solution. Is there a bettere way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DbContext.Update would be fine to fix this problem.
see:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/change-tracker